# Count the number of unique values appearing a set number of times in a range

Tags: r, excel, countif

I have a dataset in Excel that is structured as follows:

```
A    B            C
ID   Start_date   End_date
1    01/01/2000   05/01/2000
1    06/01/2000   15/05/2000
1    16/05/2000   07/04/2018
2    06/07/2016   09/10/2019
2    10/10/2019   14/12/2019
3    02/08/2000   06/08/2006
3    07/08/2006   15/02/2020
4    05/09/2012   09/11/2017
```

I would like to create a time series of the number of unique values in the above dataset that occur more than 3 times in the 12 months prior to any month in the date range covered by the dataset (in this case 01/01/2000 - 15/02/2020). So, for example, the number of unique values appearing more than three times in the 12 months prior to January 2001 would be 1 (ID = 1).

I've tried this in Excel using the following formula:

```
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(($B$2:$B$8<=EOMONTH('Time Series'!A2,0))*($C$2:$C$8>=EOMONTH('Time Series'!A2,-12),$A$2:$A$8),$A$2:$A$8)>0))}
```

Where the value in `'Time Series'!A2` is January 2001.

However, this only returns the number of unique values that occur in the 12 months prior to January 2001, not how many unique values occur more than three times in the period.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated - while I have been doing this in Excel so far, I would be open to performing the calculation in R if that would prove simpler.

Comment: Hi. Could you change the data to a factor (using `as.factor`) and run queries on that column, using either base or `dplyr::filter()`

Comment: Try changing the `>0` to `>=3`

Comment: the number of unique values appearing more than three times in the 12 months prior to January 2001 would be 1 -> but ID 1 apears exactly three times, not **more** than three times?!

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, this looked to have worked. Happy to mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly:

1.Create minimal reproducible example:

```
df <-structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L),
               Start_date = c("01/01/2000", "06/01/2000", "16/05/2000", "06/07/2016", "10/10/2019", "02/08/2000", "07/08/2006", "05/09/2012"),
               End_date = c("05/01/2000", "15/05/2000","07/04/2018", "09/10/2019", "14/12/2019", "06/08/2006", "15/02/2020", "09/11/2017")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

head(df)
```

Returns:

```
  ID Start_date   End_date
1  1 01/01/2000 05/01/2000
2  1 06/01/2000 15/05/2000
3  1 16/05/2000 07/04/2018
4  2 06/07/2016 09/10/2019
5  2 10/10/2019 14/12/2019
6  3 02/08/2000 06/08/2006
```

2. Suggested solution using dplyr

Format date columns `as.Date`:

```
library(dplyr)
df_formated <- df %>% 
  mutate(Start_date = as.Date(Start_date, "%d/%m/%Y"),
         End_date = as.Date(End_date, "%d/%m/%Y"))

str(df)
```

Returns:

```
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID        : int  1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4
 $ Start_date: chr  "01/01/2000" "06/01/2000" "16/05/2000" "06/07/2016" ...
 $ End_date  : chr  "05/01/2000" "15/05/2000" "07/04/2018" "09/10/2019" ...
```

Filter by `cutoff_date` and count occurences and filter by `min_number_of_occurences`:

```
cutoff_date <- as.Date("01/01/2001", "%d/%m/%Y")
min_number_of_occurences <- 3

df_formated %>% 
  filter(Start_date < cutoff_date) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) %>% 
  filter(N >= min_number_of_occurences)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
     ID     N
  <int> <int>
1     1     3
```

Comment: thanks - this looks to work as an R-based solution, with a couple of tweaks to convert the output into a time series